# how to render react native component in array with join()?

Tags: react-native

there is array =

```
const array = [<Text>a</Text>, <View><Text>b</Text></View>];
```

how can I render this array like below in react native?

```
<Text>a</Text>
<View>
  <Text>b</Text>
</View>
```

when I use join(), since component is object and string, I need to wrap the array with Text. and when I use reduce to change object to component like below

```
array.reduce((prev, curr) => [prev, '', curr])}
```

this code also returns string so I need to wrap array with text.
but the issue here is when I wrap them with text, view inside text is not working.

I don't know what I'm going to do with this.

thank you for reading.

Comment: Do you want to display as string or as components ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a map to display the items, something like below

```
 <View>
   {
     array.map(x=>x)
   }
 </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you would turn the array elements to a function, each element should return a function like below

```
const array = [
  () => <Text>{'This is a Text'} </Text>,
  () => (
    <View>
    <Text>{'This is a text inside View'}</Text>
    </View>
  ),
]
```

Render =>

```
{
  array.map(comp => comp())
}
```